# Split code to two classes

Tags: android

I have a class with a lot of code. I want to put some of the methods into another class, but load them from the class that i already have. I don't want to change the contentview either. I tried

Class1:

```
public class Class1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState;
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, Class2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 extends Class1 {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        method2();
    }
}
public void method2 {
    Log.e("Error", "Wut?")
}
```

When i run that code, the app just displays the error message over and over. The app is probably running the "method2" method over and over again... I just want to run the "method2"once. I don't want the code in the same file either, because there is gonna be a lot of code...

Comment: Your code in `onCreate` of `Class1` starts `Class2` which again calls `onCreate` of `Class1` which starts `Class2` and so on. You've created an never ending loop. Why are you trying to separate this code? And, is it necessary that `Class2` extends from `Class1`? If not, simple solution is that `Class2` extends `Activity`

Comment: @SvenVidak The code is 3385 lines long, and i want to make it shorter. I want to put some of the code in one class, and some other in another class. If i try to extend Activity, the contentview will change. I want to keep the same contentview, the same onClickListeners, but still load some methods from Class2

Comment: Well, then that other class you want methods to load from is not an activity but plain Java class. And then you can, in `onCreate` method of `Class1` create an object and call methods from that class: http://pastebin.com/pj3zVTRg

Comment: How do i create an object and call methods? I am pretty new to this

Comment: Never mind i solved it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is call the class2 in a object Class. Remember that is a java class so. Call it!

```
Class2 newClass = new Class2();
newClass. method2();
```

The class2 is not a activity, is only a class for has all your methods.. It is would not extends of nothing!

Answer (score 0):

As I see no sense in your approach here's a workaround.

```
public class Class1 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState;
    if(!this instanceof Class2)
    {
          Intent intent = new Intent (this, Class2.class);
          startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```